# Using Opamp as rectifier

Tags: operational-amplifier, rectifier

Schematic below is a current sensing circuit, Rs is 35u sensing resistor and current I1 is bi-directional. I am confused on why diode D2 makes this circuit a full rectifier.

Schematic: 
[image]

Simulation results on Rs and output D2 (N_HALF):
[image]

Comment: since Rs has value of u(H)? , on fluctuative load, the sensing part will resonate, and will be amplified U1. D2 will do the job to eliminate the AC signal, input for amplifier U2.

Answer (score 1):

Look at what happens at the peaks and valleys.

When the inverting input of your opamp is high, it will try to sink current, but it cannot because of diode D2.  That voltage will go across R4 and make N_HALF high.

When the inverting input is low, the opamp will now source current through D2, also making N_HALF high.  The current through R4 will be reversed.